# How to use JavaScript and HTML simultaneously in Sublime text 3?

Tags: javascript, html

I have got Javascript file. Also I have my html file. In the html head section I added:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myMiniGame.js"></script>
```

And when I enter my html file using web browser chrome, the javascript file is not showing.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what do you mean by not showing in the browser, is it not executing the desired code in your js file?

Comment: How is the editor relevant for this?

Comment: The script tag should work as it is, so we need a bit more info to solve the problem. Are you sure that `myMiniGame.js` is in the same directory as your HTML file? Otherwise consider using an absolute link starting with a slash `/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to connect HTML with JavaScript 
`<script src="myMiniGame.js"></script>` should work fine if both HTML and JavaScript files are in same directory.

If there are in different directory `<script src="<directoryName>/myMiniGame.js"></script>` lets say if your JavaScript file is in "js" folder so you have to write `<script src="js/myMiniGame.js"></script>`. This will resolve your problem.

Comment: If this answered your question, please accept it so others can see.